# iOS RestKit Entity Manager mapping Array of Objects

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am having a weird problem with mapping array of Objects to a Core Data Entry.

User Entity Mapping and objectManager code:

```
RKEntityMapping *objectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"user_id",
                                                    @"first_name": @"first_name",
                                                    @"middle_name":@"middle_name",
                                                    @"last_name":@"last_name",
                                                    @"phone":@"phone",
                                                    @"job_title":@"job_title",
                                                    @"roles":@"roles",
                                                    @"email":@"email",
                                                    @"created_at":@"created_at",
                                                    @"updated_at":@"updated_at",
                                                    @"avatar_urls":@"avatar_urls",
                                                    @"skills":@"skills",
                                                    @"interests":@"interests",
                                                    @"birth_date":@"birth_date"}];


RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [User entityMapping];

[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                       pathPattern:@"users/:id"
                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];

[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                       pathPattern:@"users"
                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

Here is a simple example of an array for User Entity.

```
{
  User1,
  User2,
  User3
}
```

Looking at debug logs from RestKit everything is mapped to the correct values. But when I look at the end results the mapped array has correct number of items but all of them are User3. Likewise the database also has User3. User1 and User2 are never stored in database.

I have been trying to figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

```
 [manager getObjectsAtPath:@"users"
                   parameters:@{@"token":token}
                      success:success failure:failure];
[
{
    "avatar_urls": {
        "large": "",
        "medium": "",
        "small": "",
        "thumb": "",
        "icon": ""
    },
    "id": 631,
    "roles": [
        "company_admin"
    ],
    "created_at": "2013-10-23T15:59:06.256-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2013-10-27T16:51:31.947-05:00",
    "skills": [],
    "interests": [],
    "birth_date": null,
    "phone_message_channel": true,
    "email_message_channel": true,
    "first_name": "User",
    "last_name": "One",
    "email": "",
    "phone": null,
    "job_title": null

},
{
    "avatar_urls": {
        "large": "",
        "medium": "",
        "small": "",
        "thumb": "",
        "icon": ""
    },
    "id": 633,
    "roles": [
        "company_admin"
    ],
    "created_at": "2013-10-23T16:07:46.472-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2013-10-27T16:51:26.148-05:00",
    "skills": [],
    "interests": [],
    "birth_date": null,
    "phone_message_channel": true,
    "email_message_channel": true,
    "first_name": "User",
    "last_name": "two",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "",
    "job_title": ""

},
{
    "avatar_urls": {
        "large": "",
        "medium": "",
        "small": "",
        "thumb": "",
        "icon": ""
    },
    "id": 632,
    "roles": [
        "company_admin"
    ],
    "created_at": "2013-10-23T16:07:12.295-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2013-11-01T20:11:26.607-05:00",
    "skills": [],
    "interests": [],
    "birth_date": "",
    "phone_message_channel": true,
    "email_message_channel": true,
    "first_name": "User",
    "last_name": "Three",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "",
    "job_title": ""
}
```

]

To reiterate in the success block mapping results shows 3 items in array and all are User 3. I also check core data and confirmed it only add/updated one row for User model.

**FIX**
Don't have points to post an answer myself.. so adding as an update

I forgot to add identificationAttributes for my User model. Once i set it to my id everything works like a charm..... =.= sleep deprivation is bad....

Comment: Show some real JSON and how you're making the request.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you set up an `RKEntityMapping` called objectMapping. Then you set up another `RKEntityMapping` called userMapping. You don't reference objetMapping again.

Either something is missing in the code you posted or objectMapping is never used and you don't have  a mapping set up for your request.

Comment: You are correct, I was just putting in all the relevant information not the whole code. I did however found the fix..... I forgot to set identificationAttributes for my user model.... thats what i get for not sleep the night before..

Comment: Depending on the version of RestKit you are using it *should* set it up automatically but always a good idea to set identificationAttributes

Comment: I am using the latest one cocoapods provided, you are right it always best to be safe than sorry. I wasted many hours on one line of code =/